# Resize embedded videos when window is resized, while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make embedded videos get resized while keeping their aspect ratio. (in this case it's 16:9)

I found a solution on this site: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

As you can see, the videos (the one I'm using is vimeo) are nicely resized while the window is being resized by the user. However I couldn't get it to work with this Javascript code.
I'm familiar with HTML and CSS, but I'm a rookie with Javascript.

Here's my HTML, I would normally use external CSS, but here I made a copy of what I'm trying to do and simplified it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="EN" style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width: device-width; initial-size: 1.0;">

        <style>
            body{
                background-color: darkolivegreen;
            }
            table{
                width: max-content;
                height: max-content;
                position: absolute;
            }
            iframe{
                width: 450px;
                height: 253.13px;
            }
            #table1{
                left: 4.2vw;
                top: 33vh;
            }
            #table2{
                right: 4.2vw;
                top: 33vh;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/385145267?color=ffffff" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/385145267?color=ffffff" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>        
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: stop using tables - that's old school. Use nested <div> tags instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the style I would have something like this:

```
iframe{
width: <multiple of 16>vh
height: <multiple of 9>vh
}
```

or you could replace the vh with vw, vmin, vmax for different effects

> em    Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)
>   ex  Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used)
>   ch  Relative to width of the "0" (zero) 
>   rem Relative to font-size of the root element
>   vw  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*
>   vh  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*
>   vmin    Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension 
>   vmax    Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension
>   %   Relative to the parent element

via https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Tried it, worked! Thank you. My only problem is that now the videos are somewhat wiggling around when resizing the window. Any idea of I should fix that? position: absolute didn't fix the problem

Comment: Humans are inherently inaccurate, we move stuff at slightly varying speeds, that may be the cause of the wiggling. for relative units, vh uses the height, vw uses the width, vmin uses the of vh and vw, and vmax uses the max of vh and vw. maybe you could use %

Comment: In the end I'm going with vh and vw then.